# Using AdSense to show ads to logged-in users

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I know that you can grant authorization permissions to Google AdSense so that it can 'log in' and see what other logged in users can see (e.g. in a private forum), so that the ads it displays are better targetted.

Extending this principle further: I am making a site which will show completely different content for each individual user (i.e. *not* 'common' content like a forum in which everybody sees essentially the same thing).  You could think of this content as similar to the way each Facebook user has a different news feed, but it is the 'same' page.

Complicating things further, the URLs for this site will be simple, e.g. '/home' and '/somepage', and will *not* usually include unique identifiers to differentiate between users (e.g. '/home?user=32i42').

**My questions are:**

- Is creating an account purely for AdSense to log in to the site with worth it in this case, seeing as it will be seeing it's own 'personalized' version and not any other user's?
- More importantly: is that against the Google AdSense Terms of Service? (I can't seem to figure that one out)
- How would you go about this problem?

Comment: This was also asked on Google Product Forums and received better answers there: http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/G-ckpqkX0zs/IqDwt1Shk0kJ

Answer (score -1):

According to Google TOS, you cannot place ads on pages which are not visible to Guests.

**Reason:** Google won't be able to display relevant ads (their spiders also won't be able to access the content for keywords).

Comment: Wrong. They have included special procedures to allow the Adsense Bot to reach user-only pages.